# C++ Print slowly but skip when user presses enter or anything. Shouldn't wait though

Tags: c++, linux

I have a C++ function here:

```
void printTextSlowly(string &s, int speed)
{
    int position = 0;
    for(char c: s)
    {
        position++;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(speed));
        std::cout << c << std::flush;

        // Should run until user presses enter.
        //if(cin.ignore())
        //{
        //    std::string subString = s.substr(position);
        //    std::cout << subString << std::endl;
        //    break;
        //}
    }
}
```

So basically this will slow the text down which it does but when user presses enter, it should stop and print out the rest of the text. With cin.ignore() it waits for the user to do something. I don't want it to wait.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: select is obsolete. Use [pool](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) instead

---

What you want is to wait for a specific amount of time or until you have something on stdin.

Since you are on linux this can be achieved with [select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html).

> ```
> int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds,
>                      fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);
> ```
>
> select() and pselect() allow a program to monitor multiple file
>          descriptors, waiting until one or more of the file descriptors become
>          "ready" for some class of I/O operation

You don't need multiple file selectors. Just stdin. And set the timeout to 1 millisecond.

Since I don't have a linux handy here is some untested code adapted from the linked page example and your example:

```
fd_set rfds;
struct timeval tv;
int retval;

/* Watch stdin to see when it has input. */

FD_ZERO(&rfds);
FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &rfds);

/* Wait 1 millisecond. */

tv.tv_sec = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 1000;

int position = 0;

for (int position = 0; position < s.length(); ++position)
{
    retval = select(1, &rfds, nullptr, nullptr, &tv);

    if (retval == -1)
    {
       perror("select()");
       // exit or throw or deal with error
    }
    else if (retval)
    {
       // Data available on cin (user pressed enter)

       std::string subString = s.substr(position);
       std::cout << subString << std::endl;
       break;
    }
    else
    {
       // No data on cin, continue printing
       std::cout << s[position] << std::flush;
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) instead of the limited and almost obsolete `select`

Comment: Is it possible with something that is in the standard library and not exclusively for Linux? Unfortunately, the project is passed around through the different Operating system, and I can not rely on something only on Window or only on Linux.

Comment: @ArminazBakh look into boost asio select. I haven't worked with it, but at a first glance it looks like it's a bit more complicated. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1) Copy the String in a new variable(until it got printed).

2) Use a do-while loop until user presses enter.

3) Find out the remaining string and print after ending the do-while loop.

Hope it helps :)